# Supabase auth state lags behind when used in Root Layout (Next.js App router)

Tags: next.js, supabase, supabase-js, next.js14

I've encountered an unusual behavior in my Next.js app (latest version, using App Router) integrated with Supabase Auth. I'm leveraging the Supabase auth state to conditionally render login/logout buttons based on the user's authentication status.

The issue arises when a new user completes the registration flow and is automatically logged in to a protected route after a successful signup. In this scenario, the auth buttons on the root layout are not re-rendered to reflect the correct state (e.g., displaying the Logout button).

However, when I place the AuthButtons inside the protected route page (server-side rendered as well), the state is correctly reflected.

This behavior seems to occur only during the automatic login directly after the signup process. Subsequent logins through the regular flow result in the correct state being reflected in the Root Layout.

I'm seeking guidance on how to debug this issue or any insights into what might be causing this behavior. Any help would be appreciated!

I've included a minimal example below.

Root layout (Does not work):

```
import AuthButtonServer from './components/ui/AuthButtonServer'

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export default async function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <main>
          {children}
        </main>
        <AuthButtonServer />
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

AuthButtonServer:

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

import { createClient } from '@/utils/supabase/server'
import AuthButtonClient from './AuthButtonClient'

const AuthButtonServer = async () => {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const supabase = createClient(cookieStore)
  const {
    data: { session },
  } = await supabase.auth.getSession()

  return <AuthButtonClient session={session} />
}

export default AuthButtonServer
```

AuthButtonClient

```
'use client'

import LogoutButton from './LogoutButton'
import LoginButton from './LoginButton'
import { Session } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const AuthButtonClient = ({ session }: { session: Session | null }) => {
  return <>{session ? <LogoutButton /> : <LoginButton />}</>
}

export default AuthButtonClient
```

SSR Page (Protected route) - Works:

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

import { createClient } from '@/utils/supabase/server'
import AuthButtonServer from '../components/ui/AuthButtonServer'

export const dynamic = 'force-dynamic'

export default async function Dashboard() {
  const cookieStore = cookies()
  const supabase = createClient(cookieStore)

  const {
    data: { session },
  } = await supabase.auth.getSession()

  if (!session) {
    redirect('/sign-in')
  }

  return (
    <>
      <AuthButtonServer />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: It seems like some of the code you are using is outdated. If you create a new app using `npx create-next-app -e with-supabase`, you can see the current recommended approach for implementing auth on Next.js. You could compare your code with it, and potentially fix your issue.